# How to delete completely one element from a column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, strip

I have This Column:

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant']:


0        2013/11/14 17:00
1        2013/11/14 18:00
2        2013/11/14 19:00
.
.
.
```

When I Had a look at it's values , this is what i found:

```
Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'].value_counts():

2013/12/10 16:00    33
2013/12/11 19:00    33
2013/12/09 17:00    33
.
.
.
DateTIme             3
```

And I want to get rid of that 'DateTIme' , cause otherwise i can not convert the column into a datetime .

Any Suggestion Would much appreciated , thanks all.

Comment: still there , after running Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'].value_counts() , the 'DateTIme' was there !!!

Comment: check if there are spaces around 'DateTIME'

Comment: `Mi_Meteo=Mi_Meteo.loc[Mi_Meteo['Time_Instant'] != 'DateTIme',:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose such solution:

```
df['time']=np.where((df['time'].str.contains('DateTIme')),np.nan,df['time'])
df.time.dropna(how='all').to_frame()
```